# Как сделать, чтобы по умолчанию при открытии приложения открывался определенный фрагмен?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-material

У меня есть Nav Drawer, но при запуске приложения, никакой фрагмент не открывается, следовательно мы видим белый экран. Как сделать, чтобы по умолчанию при открытии приложения открывался определенный фрагмент?

Comment: Эмулируйте нажатие на меню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в `onCreate` сразу вызвать код, показывающий определённый фрагмент. Чтобы избежать дублирования, рекомендуется код, отвечающий за показ фрагментов, вынести из обработчика `NavigationView` меню в отдельный метод.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private NavigationView drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        drawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        drawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        selectMenuItem(R.id.fragment_1_item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        selectMenuItem(menuItem.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    private void selectMenuItem(int index) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (index) {
            case R.id.fragment_1_item:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case R.id.fragment_2_item:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case R.id.exit_item:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        if (fragment == null) return;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Здесь у нас есть метод `selectMenuItem`, отвечающий за обработку пунктов меню. Теперь его можно вызвать в `onCreate` с нужным индексом (`selectMenuItem(R.id.fragment_1_item)`.